# How do I create a 'Message of the Day' in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

Is it possible to pull from some sort of feed to display a different quote in a Text Field each day? I have a list of 365 quotes that I would like to display in the app each day.

Comment: You create some sort of non-volatile data storage (a property list, an SQL database, whatever) which associates day numbers with each quote. Then you use `NSCalendar`, `NSCalendarDate`, `NSDateComponent`, `NSDate`, etc. (just google their docs) to obtain a day number.

Answer (score 0):

make a json file with all your messages, parse them, iterate over them and display one per day.

shouldn't be too hard!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your response! I am new to this website, as well as iOS development.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: i'm not into ios development myself, but see H2CO3's answer!